# How to retrieve user info fra a Active Directory Security Group using LDAP and PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, single-sign-on

As you can see below I'm not getting any user info when I do a LDAP search to the security group. I want to use the `$_SERVER[remote_user]` to check if the user is a member of this group. I would also like to retrieve the info of this user and update the sql database with it. Is this possible?

```
$dn = "CN=Intra,OU=Common Security Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=local";
$filter = "(member=*)";

$ad = ldap_connect("IP") or die("Couldn't connect to AD!");
ldap_set_option($ad, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
$bd = ldap_bind( $ad, "username@mydomain.local", "password") or die("Can't bind to server.");
$sr = ldap_search($ad,$dn,$filter);
$entries = ldap_get_entries($ad, $sr);
```

`print_r($entries);`

Returns this:

```
Array
(
    [count] => 1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [objectclass] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 2
                    [0] => top
                    [1] => group
                )

            [0] => objectclass
            [cn] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => Intra
                )

            [1] => cn
            [description] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => Group for (LDAP) INTRANET server access
                )

            [2] => description
            [member] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 4
                    [0] => CN=Fname1 Lname1,OU=Mail enabled users,OU=Aberdeen,DC=mydomain,DC=local
                    [1] => CN=Fname2 Lname2,OU=Mail enabled users,OU=Forres,DC=mydomain,DC=local
                    [2] => CN=Fname3 Lname3,OU=Houston,DC=mydomain,DC=local
                    [3] => CN=Fname4 Lname4,OU=Mail enabled users,OU=Bergen,DC=mydomain,DC=local
                )

            [3] => member
            [distinguishedname] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => CN=Intra,OU=Common Security Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=local
                )

            [4] => distinguishedname
            [instancetype] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => 4
                )

            [5] => instancetype
            [whencreated] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => 20100711172407.0Z
                )

            [6] => whencreated
            [whenchanged] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => 20100712063949.0Z
                )

            [7] => whenchanged
            [usncreated] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => 17491499
                )

            [8] => usncreated
            [usnchanged] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => 17498823
                )

            [9] => usnchanged
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => Intra
                )

            [10] => name
            [objectguid] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] =>
                )

            [11] => objectguid
            [objectsid] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] =>
                )

            [12] => objectsid
            [samaccountname] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => Intra
                )

            [13] => samaccountname
            [samaccounttype] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => 268435456
                )

            [14] => samaccounttype
            [grouptype] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => -2147483646
                )

            [15] => grouptype
            [objectcategory] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => CN=Group,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=mydomain,DC=local
                )

            [16] => objectcategory
            [count] => 17
            [dn] => CN=Intra,OU=Common Security Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=local
        )

)
```

Everything worked fine when I used the normal DN:

```
$dn = "OU=Mail enabled users,OU=Bergen,DC=mydomain,DC=local";
```

But a AD expert told me this was a big NO-NO and that I should use Security Groups instead :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query the AD like this:

```
$dn       = "DC=mydomain,DC=local";
$group_DN = "CN=Intra,OU=Common Security Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=local";
$filter   = "(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=$group_DN))";
// ...
$sr       = ldap_search($ad, $dn, $filter);
```

Have a look at the [MSDN article about the LDAP search filter syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(VS.85).aspx) for info on more complex filters.

Be sure to pay attention to the **Special Characters** section down on that page. A correct solution must pass `$group_DN` through an escaping mechanism before using it in the filter string!

Always try build filters as specific as possible. It is more efficient to let the LDAP server sort out records you don't want, instead of having more records transferred over the wire than you need and throw away half of them on the client.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! But when I try to use your filter I get this error: PHP Warning: ldap_search() [function.ldap-search]: Search: Operations error in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\test.php on line 33 PHP Warning: ldap_get_entries(): supplied argument is not a valid ldap result resource in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\test.php on line 35

Comment: Since I see that you are on Windows, here's a tip. Download Softerra LDAP Browser 2.6 (it's free), connect it to your AD and test your searches with the tool. -- In theory, a base DN of `"DC=mydomain,DC=local"` should work, though.

Comment: Thanks. Now I don't know what the hell is going on. I did a search for DN: "DC=mydomain,DC=local" FILTER: "(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=CN=Intra,OU=Common Security Groups,DC=mydomain,DC=local))" in the LDAP browser with no problems at all. But when i try to do the same thing in PHP i get this error: "PHP Warning: ldap_search() [function.ldap-search]: Search: Operations error in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\test.php on line 17" :( I don't get any errors if I use "OU=Bergen,DC=mydomain,DC=local". But then i have to create a for loop for each OU.

Comment: I see you mention Special Characters. Maybe the error has something to do with it. But I'm not sure I understand it :\

Comment: @cvack: See this thread (http://drupal.org/node/55735), the issue seems to be described there. Scroll to post #9 and see if that helps. Also check your `ldap_bind()` parameters, usually you bind to AD with a full distinguished name (DN), not with the `"user@domain"` syntax.

Comment: @cvack: Did it work the way they said in that forum thread? Or was it the changed user name for `ldap_bind()` that made the difference?

Comment: Well first of all, "user" is not a valid value for objectCategory - use "person". Also, to add to the original answer, I recommend to reorder the conditions because there will statistically be less users in a group than all the "persons" in the directory, making the search query run more quickly: "(&(memberOf=$group_DN)(objectCategory=user))"

Answer (score 0):

Tomalak

I think the problem is that not all users in the Security Group comes from the same OU.

If I change

```
$dn       = "DC=mydomain,DC=local";
```

to

```
$dn       = "OU=Bergen,DC=mydomain,DC=local";
```

the filter works. But I also have 2 more OU's with users.

Comment: Please use the "Answers" section for actual answers to the question (yes, you can answer your own questions). For mere comments, please use the comment feature.