# Authenticate users using access direcrory

Tags: php, ldap

I have a php login form localhost and I want to use the same username/password that I have when I open my computer instead of  create new password. While I was searching this, I read that I must use LDAP .But I need your help because is existing a mess and I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

1st, it call Active Directory (AD). Yes in order to allow communicate PHP to communicate to AD, you will use LDAP lib.

Make sure:

- AD Domain Controller (DC) allow 3rd party communication; eg server firewall.
- PHP compiled with LDAP library, enabled.
- Have details such as Path, DC & Domain Name (DN) string.

Then either use:

- Community classes: https://github.com/adldap/adLDAP, or
- https://maychia.wordpress.com/2012/10/08/how-tophp-ldap-authentication-active-directory/

**Updated:**

- To get the AD IP, try `ipconfig -all` or `ifconfig -all`; DC normally listed as one of the DNS server(s).
- Basic Connection PHP-LDAP https://pastebin.com/GR0gHFXi

  - change values on `CONFIG HERE` comments.

Comment: How check if AD Domain Controller (DC) allow 3rd party communication?

Comment: 1: simple ping. 2: php fsockopen("IP/hostname - if dns-able", 389 or 636, 'str', 'str', 5). 3: php ldap_connect().

Comment: Can you particularly explain me ?

Comment: #1 is just getting the IP, check DNSs server if responding to ping. #2 & #3 in link given above.

Comment: Thanks you very much about your help!!

Comment: I use the code from here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773643/using-active-directory-to-authenticate-users-on-intranet-site but when write username and password ,display unable to access:success

Comment: whats the error? note there are domain-name prefix to username.. and username is not email. ie "xyz\user.name"

Comment: Firstly i dont have prefix in my fomain. Secondly it is very straight that display unable to access:success with the correct username and password

Comment: so during your troubleshooting everything is ok? post your code, AD structure screenshot.. or something